# Hibernate eagerly load collection in collection

Tags: xml, hibernate, mapping

I got 2 classes:

```
Class1{ 
    Class2 class2
}
```

```
Class2{
    List<class1> class1
}
```

Now I want to get an object of class1. With lazy loading disabled I get the  `class2` attribute.
But I don't get `class2.class1`. How can I load the list now?
I mean how can I load all the information I want in only one request.
I disabled lazy loading in both mappings.
I dont need `class1.class2.class1.class2`, I just need `class1.class2.class1`